# Any websites or resources for planning my trip around Europe?

Tags: europe, planning, online-resources, backpacking

I have been looking around the internet for sites that will help you plan your route around the world. Apart from Google maps or Bing maps who only work from A->B i have been unable to find anything else decent.

For me I am planning a 2-3 month trip around Europe with many countries. At the moment I have this route in my head but It does not adhere to Rail, Road or Air routes. So Im hoping there is something out there that will help me plan my route so I can use the best methods for transport etc.

Here is my journey plan in its crudest form.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used [Tripline](http://www.tripline.net) to show where I've been on recent trips.  Again it's point A to B, but at least you can easily share it on facebook or a blog.  For example, my 2010 South American journey map is embedded on [my blog](http://www.marksmayo.com/south-american-journey/).

They are in beta and seem to be adding new features fairly recently.  I'd love them to add the ability to show two people travelling at once - like if you were racing someone across Europe, showing where you each were at diff times on the same map would look awesome.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit late for you, but there's a website now for your purpose. http://www.vamo.com can help you plan this multi city trip. You just add all the cities into the trip, it will try to find the best transportation for you (including flight/train/rental car/etc), so you don't have to do all the searches yourself.

If you have specific ordering in mind, you can switch to the "custom ordering" model and drag and drop the cities into the order you like. Then you can pick the choose the transportation to fit your need.

The only thing that it doesn't have is generating your map with arrows :)

Answer (score 0):

I have been used the [TripIt.com](http://www.tripit.com). This website and app has some incredible tools.

You can assign your email account for the service read the content of your emails and organize the map for you. At first moment is a little scary a external tool reading your emails. But this is really helpfull.

After received the confirmations emails from the hotels, flights, rent car, reservation in restaurants, you have all this information in the app. Of course the app make some statics for you. Number of travels, kilometers and other statistics informations.

The tripIt has a version pro, but since I started to used this app I never fell the necessity to upgrade the app.

[image]
[image]